# Issue with a form validation into a Spring MVC liferay portlet

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, liferay

I am building a Spring MVC Liferay 6.2 portlet.
I have a form with 2 buttons.
First button validates the form (submit).
The second one redirects to a jsp.
I have a difficulty to have it completely as I need.

Ideally, I would do this:

```
<form ...>
...
<div class="controls-row  ">
             <label class="span1"   ></label>
             <input class="span2 btn " type="submit" value="Submit Form" > 
             <label class="span4"   ></label>
             <button  class="span2 btn " onClick="<%=viewLogsURL.toString()%>" value="View Logs" />
        </div>
</form>
```

If I use this code, the 2 buttons are correctly displayed with bootstraps2 (span2 class applies and each button consumes 2/12 of the screen).
BUT ... the second button does not redirect to viewLogsURL as it should and it submits the form (just like the first button).

Alternatively, if I use this code:

```
<form ...>
...
<div class="controls-row  ">
             <label class="span1"   ></label>
             <input class="span2 btn " type="submit" value="Submit Form" > 
             <label class="span4"   ></label>
             <aui:button  class="span2 btn " onClick="<%=viewLogsURL.toString()%>" value="View Logs" />
        </div>
</form>
```

I have just replaced the second  with a , then the second button correctly behaves (redirects to viewLogsURL) but the span2 class does not apply anymore...

Is there a way to have the button to redirect and the span2 class to apply?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form ...>
...
    <div class="controls-row  ">
        <label class="span1"   ></label>
        <input class="span2 btn " type="submit" value="Submit Form" > 
        <label class="span4"   ></label>
        <input type="button" class="span2 btn" onClick="<%=viewLogsURL.toString()%>" value="View Logs" />
    </div>
</form>
```

If i remember the `button` tag do submit by default.

Comment: This makes no action.